# Old kitchen range only has 3-wires, how to wire correctly to 4 wire circuit

Tags: electrical, 240v, range

So I have an old range that I'll probably replace soon, so I decided to inspect the wiring box under the counter.

I wanted to make sure everything is safe when I wire the new range to the dedicated range 220V 4-wire (red, black, white, and bare Cu/ground) circuit. However, when I opened the junction box I noticed the following:

- the range only has 3 wires: red,black, green.
- the red wire nut splice looked burned, the plastic nut melted and was almost exposed
- the neutral wire from the circuit was not connected at all any of the range's 3 wires
- **The range's green wire was connected to ground.** This is wrong right?

I cut and cleaned the burned wire/nuts, and spliced it as such:

[image: Here's a pic of after a bit of clean up.]

So question: Is this wiring correct? I thought that in 3-wire ranges there's no ground, and the range's green wire was understood to be neutral..? And range's green should've been connected to the circuits white neutral?

What's the correct wiring here? range green => neutral **OR** range green => neutral+ground ?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE: So it's a very simple cooktop range (no oven), 4 coils, no digital clock, analog knob controls. The dedicated circuit powering it seems to be at least #10 gauge NM 3-wire + bare ground cable, and it's on a double 50A breaker.**

**UPDATE2: Here's the label for the cooktop:**
[image: cooktop label]

Comment: It appears that you have two different wire gauges there, places where the insulation is burned and burned through.  All of those are RED FLAGS that your existing installation was inadequate.  Chances are that your new range will need MORE power than the old one.  Be sure your circuit is up to the task.  It looks like it is not.

Comment: If your task right now is to make sure the existing range is connected properly then you may want to pull the panel on the back of the range and take a photo of how these wires are connected to the range.

Comment: @jwh20 -- it's normal for the appliance whip that comes with a hardwired appliance to use different size wire than the branch circuit feeding it as it operates under a different set of controlling rules.  The burning is defintely a concern, but more than likely the result of bad splicing

Comment: How hard of a haul would it be to replace this circuit outright? It seems the prior installer cut some corners here...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I like the way the installer "screwed" the whip into the box ... lol

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel But it's not normal to be burned like that!

Comment: @jwh20 -- yeah, the burns are *definitely* not normal, I'm chalking them up to a bad/failed splice though

Comment: Was the existing range a range with top elements and an oven in the same box, or purely a cooktop (just top elements, no oven)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just a cooktop (4 burners) no oven

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's a very simple cooktop, 4 resistance coils, no clocks, or anything digital.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the easy one:

> The range's green wire was connected to ground. This is wrong right?

Actually, that is correct!

Now on with the show:

The usual correct wiring for a range is:

- 2 x hot = typically black & red
- 1 neutral = white
- 1 ground = green or bare (or metal conduit)

In addition, the wires must be properly sized based on the current used by the range (big enough), and the breaker must be sized accordingly (small enough). For example, a 30A circuit will require at least 10 AWG wire (8 AWG is fine, 12 AWG is not) and a 30A breaker (smaller will result in nuisance trips, larger will not protect the wires from overheating).

**You need to figure out what size wires and what size breaker you currently have.** You may need to upsize one or (more likely) both to properly support the new range.  **Need to check with specifications of the new range.**

There are certain situations - and you have at least one of these - where you only need 3 wires:

- If the range **only uses 240V** and does not make use of 120V power at all, then it does not need or use a neutral, or have any connection for a neutral wire. That **appears** to be the case here. Most, but not all, newer ranges use 120V to power clock, timer, controls, etc.
- If the range was installed a long time ago on a circuit that was installed a very long time ago, then a separate ground wire was not originally needed and *ground and neutral combined* was permitted at the time and is a grandfathered exception. In some places it is still a grandfathered exception. However, if upgrades to the wiring are needed (e.g., to change from 10 AWG to 8 AWG wire) then the exception goes away. **This is not the case here, as you already have a 4-wire supply!**

**As far as the burn marks, etc. Those are serious problems.** They could be due to undersized wires, but more likely due to loose connections. A loose connection can lead to arcing and burning and/or be high resistance which leads to overheating and burning. So cleaning up those connections is critical. I am extra concerned about the burning on the white (neutral) wire, which since it was not even connected should never overheat! Which indicates that there was likely some serious arcing going on that it burned the otherwise inert wire.

As noted, the range whip installation is not correct, and clearly there were other problems as well. Cleaning all of that up will help for now, but it may need to be all redone for the new range with new wires. I would certainly be concerned about the damage to that white wire since it will likely be needed for the new range.

You need to figure out what kind of wires you have (cable or individual wires, what size), what breaker you have, and what breaker/wire will be needed for the new range in order to decide exactly how to proceed with replacement.

---

Based on comments, updates, etc. This appears to be 8 AWG on a 50A double-breaker. Typically 8 AWG wire should have a 40A (or smaller) breaker. There are plenty of options that should work fine with that. I picked a GE 30" slide-in range with 4 burners and a self-cleaning oven at random from Home Depot, and the manual shows 240V @ 40A. So there is a good chance that if you swap the 50A breaker for a 40A breaker and clean up the wiring that you will be able to use this for a new range.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's at least 8AWG NM the OP has there (10AWG NM would not have stranded wires in it), and by Code, that's good for any range up to about 13kW or so

Comment: That makes sense, because if it was individual wires instead of NM (I can't tell for sure, but maybe you can) then I would expect a green ground rather than a bare ground. But then there is a question of whether is any accessible slack in the cable to be able to pull out some more and cut off the damaged parts.

Comment: @threephaseeel you can get stranded nmb all the way down to 14 awg. It costs more because it is not used as often. But with a green pulled it is probably conduit of some type.

Comment: @EdBeal -- the green in this case is coming from the old range's flex whip, there's a bare ground in the box as well that's coming from the branch circuit NM

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact so the burn on the white wire I think just comes from the way it was folded close to the bad red-wire splice. I'm 100% sure the neutral was just close to the splice and part of the insulation jacket got a bit charred.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it's a basement subpanel off main home's main breaker box. In the subpanel the stove/range has it's own circuit with a 50A double breaker.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the NM cable from the breaker to the range is 3-wire (red-black-white+bare ground)... I think this basement was finished in 2005 so it's not THAT old...

Comment: The cooktop's circuit I think has #8 wire.. each wire inside has like 4 solid strands, and it's thick as hell. The range's whip wires are thinner and stranded tho.

Comment: Since your existing range is just a cooktop, it probably uses less power, so the whip wires being smaller actually makes sense. That being said, there is the question of whether 8 AWG == 50A breaker. I'm not sure if that is allowed or not - first search says "no", but I am not a pro and there are some funny legal exceptions in some cases. For sure 8 AWG is enough for at least 40A, so the right answer may depend on what your new range actually specifies. Agree regarding the neutral - the issue on neutral (and the black & red) is whether taping up the damage is enough or if you really

Comment: need new clean wire. Because if you need new clean wire and there isn't slack somewhere then you either end up with splicing an extension (not so easy - another box, etc.) or running a new cable.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact #8 copper should be on a 40A breaker. #6 can be on a 50A or possibly a 60A breaker.

Comment: @Craig That sounds like the usual to me. Meaning that (a) it is currently **wrong** and (b) before doing anything else, need to find out specs for new range.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- one of the most irksome things one runs into when spec'ing ranges, etc is that the total nameplate kilowattage of the range isn't one of the range's published spec's half the time!  (Likewise with dryers and other appliances)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel True. But some of them (like the GE I checked) actually **specify a breaker size**. Then it is easy.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Splicing in additional wire - means a junction box and other rules to follow. If my memory serves me right - there is some places where this is not allowed. I cant remember as my time reading it was quite a long time ago probably 5 years or so..